# How do I automatically archive a google sheet with a google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that is scraping data from a table from an html homepage.

The data is in a simple google sheet with A1:H1 containing the headers/labels and A2:H2 containing the values

Every time that data changes, every time my google sheet is updated with new data, I want the new data from A2:H2 to be "archived"/copied automatically to another google (sub)sheet.

Apparently, I can do this with a Google Script (that is then run automatically every day with a trigger) - I tried to use this tutorial here: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2469616/business-intelligence/business-intelligence-79661-how-to-create-an-automatically-updating-spreadsheet.html#slide7

The code they have/give is:

```
function storeData(){
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();
var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;
sheet.getRange(1,nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++){
var numLikes = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(numLikes);
}
}
```

When I run this I get the following error: "sheet" is not defined

So, do I need to put in the data range I want to copy between ()? Like this?

```
function storeData(){
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange(A2:H2);
var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();
var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;
sheet.getRange(1,nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++){
var numLikes = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(numLikes);
}
}
```

When I run this I get the following error: missing ")" sign in line 2

Can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome. Typically there's some establishing code such as `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`, `var sheet = ss.getActivesheet;`. Anyway, that's your problem, "sheet" is never defined. Add these two lines at the start of "storeData" and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define sheet.

```js
function storeData(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); // Select Spreadsheet by ID
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name'); // Select your Sheet by its Name
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();
  var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;

  sheet.getRange(1,nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++){
var numLikes = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(numLikes);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That works but as it its from this Computerworld Tutorial to collect likes from Twitter Accounts it only collected the likes for one sample account to track (Tutorial: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2469616/business-intelligence/business-intelligence-79661-how-to-create-an-automatically-updating-spreadsheet.html#slide7

I renamed 'numLikes' to 'numPoll' but I want to copy not only the value from A2 but also
A) copy the values and text in the cells from the range A2:H2
B) copy them not into a new column but in a new row
C) copy them to another sheet

Comment: Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ms7ev367olpEInRniRHKRC7vLb1N9R6taGWlKESbYkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe we can also borrow code from this tutorial? https://ctrlq.org/code/20239-copy-google-spreadsheets However when I tried it just by replacing the yellow text with the source and target spreadsheet the code did not work/gave out an error.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291549/copy-a-range-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another?rq=1

Comment: function CopyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetid'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('sheetname'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:G50'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('sheetname2'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,49,7).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

}

Answer (score 0):

The first error occurs because `sheet` isn't defined. There are several ways to define it. If the sheet to be archived will be always the same, use

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace Sheet1 by the actual name of the sheet to be archived
```

The second error occurs because `getDataRange` should not include any argument. Instead of

```
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange(A2:H2);
```

use

```
var datarange = sheet.getRange('A2:H2');
```